# Не меняется css/js на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, css, css3, веб-программирование

Смотрю через инстепктор в браузере где лежит нужный файл стилей, подключаюсь по FTP, вношу правки в файл со стилями, сохраняю изменения, записываю измененный файл обратно на сервер, но правки не применяются. Т.е даже спустя 10 минут, я перезагружаю страницу с очисткой кэша страницы (ctrl+shift+r), но не смотря на то, что данные в файле уже другие, браузер по прежнему видит старые стили в этом файле. 
Даже если я удаляю/переименовываю файл со стилями, на который указывает мне инспектор, то браузер все-равно продолжает ссылаться на этот файл со стилями.

Подозреваю, что проблема в кэшировании на стороне сервера. Но обычно, если происходит кэширование, то инспектор ссылается на кэшированный файл, который можно открыть и внести правки и они пременятся (знаю, что это плохой вариант) или удалить вовсе этот файл с кэшем в ручную и все.

Касательно js, все еще интереснее. Если я вношу правки в файл, то примерно каждые 10 минут, инспектор отображает разные данные в этом файле. (сначала те, которые были изначально, спустя 10 минут инспектор видет в этом файле другой код, который я внес в этот файл, спустя еще 10 минут он опять отображает в этом файле старый код, которого по факту там уже давно нет)

Жду ваших комментариев/советов/объяснений по этой проблеме.

Comment: У меня такое было на reg помогло отключение кеша в настройках хостинга. Вполне может быть у вас подобная проблема. Посмотрите, может хостер как-то кеширует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в кешировании браузером. Обычно это фиксят подключением скриптов с get парметрами, например, времени. Вот пример для чистого php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=/path.js?<?=$cur_time;?>"></script>
```

Если работаете с фреймворком, посмотрите, как решают эту проблему на нем

Comment: Если бы проблема была в кэшировании на стороне браузера, то после очистки кэша браузера проблема должна была бы быть решена, разве не так?

Comment: так. но это решение подходит и при кешировании сервером, хотя лучше смотреть настройки для конкретного типа сервера

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> или <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> в моём случае срабатывали не всегда.

Но вот <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> в большинстве случаев решает проблему.